# End-user scripting

Tags: javascript, python, lua, sandbox

I'd like to provide end-user scripting (that would run server-side) in an application. I've been reading around, and found that sandboxing is much more of a problem than I thought.

I don't really care *what* the language is. LUA, Python, JavaScript, I'm fine with anything readable.

How hard is it to run a function in an untrusted script, passing in some information and obtaining some more? I've read JVM Security Manager is a no-go and that Python is nearly unsandboxable, but I have very little knowledge on the topic and can't really judge the sources.

How can I, for example, interpret a function in JS that takes a JSON (from, say, Java, or Python, or even node.js), and get back the returned JSON?

I'd like to avoid implementing a pythonish i-just-know-it-will-suck language interpreter myself.

Comment: JavaScript seems like the safest option here. It's basically designed for this exact purpose.

Comment: As to sandboxing Python, there is [some advice](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Asking%20for%20Help/How%20can%20I%20run%20an%20untrusted%20Python%20script%20safely%20%28i.e.%20Sandbox%29) out there.

Comment: @Lattyware: The advise for securing CPython there is basically useless, IMHO. They recommend chrooting (which is unsafe) and virtualization (which is expensive).

Comment: LUA has had a lot of success being embedded, partly due to its low memory requirements and the fact that you can easily strip out all the parts you don't need.

Comment: @NiklasB. This is true, apparently Jython might work though. I admit it's probably not the best suited to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lua has good sandboxing capabilities and is clean and simple.

It has the [setfenv()](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_setfenv) function that can run code in a specific environment. The untrusted code can only access what is in the specific environment.
For C functions, such as `string.rep`, you can prevent memory over-consumption by replacing them with Lua functions or providing a custom memory allocator to `lua_newstate`.

Also, if you decide that you wish to use Lua for trusted code and have it interface with untrusted code, you can use [coroutines](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.2) and [`debug.sethook`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-debug.sethook) to control CPU usage.

The Lua Wiki has a simple [example sandbox](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SandBoxes).
The [source code](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#demo) of the [lua live demo](http://www.lua.org/demo.html) might be of interest, too.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation and references! I read around, and decided I'll go with this and see where it leads me. It looks great!

Answer (score 1):

Tcl has a very strong sanbox model, and arguably one of the better languages for end user scripting. You can read more about it on the [safe interpreter](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/safe.htm) man page.